# "Retag Questions" vs "Create your own tags" privileges

Tags: discussion, tags, privileges

I've just been awarded the "Create tags" privilege but I think that it should be granted after the ability to "retag questions" as this in my mind is related more closely to review ability.  Not sure this qualifies as a question but as a suggestion.

Anyone has any opinions for or against?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reputation needed to create tags is only greater than the reputation needed to retag on Stack Overflow where there is a problem with people creating bad tags, but even there it only needs 1,500 points (as opposed to 300 everywhere else).

If there's seen to be a problem with low reputation users creating bad tags then the reputation score needed can be raised - but it's a developer function.